# How to display and get the value chosen in an User field?

Tags: development, web-part, event-handlers, user, spfield

I'm very new at Sharepoint and I faced to a trick issue.

Here is the situation :
in an .aspx.cs file, I've created an EventHandler called btnValidate_Click, raised on a click on a button. In this EventHandler, I need to get values of some fields displayed on the page, in order to insert them in various lists.

In one of my list, I have a User column, and I would like to display it, get the value defined by the end-user, and insert it in my list.

Here is my code :

```
<table>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RepeaterWorkTeamUser" DataSourceID="SPDataSourceWorkTeam" EnableViewState="true">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr>
            <%-- Headers --%>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTitle" EnableViewState="true" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <%--Some others fields --%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <SharePoint:UserField runat="server" ID="spufManager" EnableViewState="true" ControlMode="Edit" Visible="true" />
            </td>
            <td>
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</table>
```

In my btnValidate_Click EventHandler, this is how I get my values :

```
public void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPList listWorkers = web.Lists["WorkTeam"];

        foreach (RepeaterItem i in RepeaterWorkTeamUser.Items)
        {
            SPListItem workTeamListItem = listWorkers.AddItem();

            TextBox txtNom = (TextBox)i.FindControl("txtName");
            workTeamListItem["Nom"] = txtNom.Text;

            <%-- Some others properties --%>

            SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, web.CurrentUser.ID, web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
            workTeamListItem["Manager"] = userValue;

            workTeamListItem.Update();
        }
```

But the field "Manager" doesn't even appear on my page, whereas others fields are correctly displayed, and their values are correctly inserted on the list.

I tried with a

Can somebody help me to display it correctly, and get the chosen user in my EventHandler to add it to my list ?

Thanks in advance :-)

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

I'm still unable to display a , so I used a PeopleEditor as explained here : http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/peopleeditor-control/

Then, in my aspx.cs file, here is how I get the selected user :

```
PeopleEditor peManager = (PeopleEditor)i.FindControl("peManager");
peResponsable.AutoPostBack = true;
PickerEntity pe = (PickerEntity)peManager.Entities[0];
workTeamListItem["Manager"] = pe.EntityData["SPUserID"];
```

Fix it !

Oh, by the way
If you experience an issue with IE9, like "Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined" when submitting datas, follow this link and look like the M_Olson's answer : his solution perfectly works.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/90b3835c-6754-4bb6-9fd4-b74f16f236ff
I also use this other M_Olson's answer for this IE9 issue :
http://*social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/8457c2f7-70f7-4500-a71c-31b1cf2b22eb

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the following code:

```
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser("{user login}");
item["Manager"] = user;
item.Update();
```

Comment: I tried your sample, but I don't know the user login because the end-user has to type it... I replace your {"user login"} by userValue, definied as follow : SPFieldUserValue userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, ufResponsable.ItemId, ufResponsable.Value.ToString()); but it didn't work and my <SharePoint:FormField> still doesn't appear on my webpage...
Any other idea ?

Comment: What type is "ufResponsable"?